# How to print a page in particular printer using IP address. in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, printing, ip

I am new to react native, I m developing an app, now i want to print a page, I have used react-native-print package to print the page. But it just go to the scanning page and ask to select a printer and etc. but I want to print in particular printer using IP address. How i do this. pls answer.